# Spring, modelmap, getting attributes for displaying Lists in JSTL <c:foreach>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I, a newbie in progrmming, develop spring MVC application with spring mvc frameworks. I want to list the data into table by using JSTL  with 2 mapped entities.

```
<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="emp">
<tr class="odd gradeX">
     <td>${emp.icode}</td>
     <td>${emp.employeeName}</td>
     //problem here
     //I want to get employee's phone num 
     <td>${emp.ph_number}</td>                                              
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This is the example of my Entity,
1) Employee Entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long employeeId;
private String employeeName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee" ,cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Phone>phones;

//method getter setter }
```

2)Phone Entity

```
@Entity
public class Phone implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

private long phoneId;
private String ph_number;

@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;
//method getter setter}
```

3)Enployee Controller

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
@EJB(mappedName = "ejb:/EJB//EmployeeServiceBean!com.mfu.ejb.EmployeeService")
EmployeeService empServ;
@RequestMapping("/listEmp")
public ModelAndView listEmployee(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("ListEmp.jsp");

    List<Employee> empList;
    try {
        empList = empServ.getAllEmployee();
        mv.addObject("empList", empList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mv;
}
}
```

Thankyou and sorry for my bad English. Hope it make sence.

Comment: Well, use another forEach to loop over the phones in employee and display each of them.

Comment: I got an error with "does not have the property 'ph_number'."

Comment: Yes, indeed, an employee doesn't have a property ph_number. Just read your own code. What an employee has is a property `phones`, which is a List<Phone>. So you need to use **another** forEach loop to iterate over these phones, and display the property `ph_number` of the current phone in the list. Just like you would use an inner for loop in Java.

Comment: Hi, JB Nizet , I have tried it. it lists out All of the the ph_number including the one that not belonging. How can I check the id of employee for each phone loop

Comment: Then you must have a bug in your code, or in your data. Show your code, show your data, debug your code to know what each employee contains.